# How to expose existing property on Obj-C class using an extension protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

In Swift 1.1 we were able to have code like below compile and work where we exposed existing Objective-C properties through a protocol added by an extension.  We also had a few where the property is handled by the extension.

```
@objc protocol Enableable: class {
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}

let DisabledAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5
let EnabledAlpha: CGFloat = 1.0

extension UIButton: Enableable {}

extension UIImageView: Enableable {
    var enabled: Bool {
        get {
            return alpha > DisabledAlpha
        }
        set(enabled) {
            alpha = enabled ? EnabledAlpha : DisabledAlpha
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to compile this code using XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2, we get the following error `Type 'UIButton' does not conform to the protocol 'Enableable'`.  The UIImageView extension seems to compile fine.

Is there any way to expose these sort of existing properties from an Objective-C type or do we have to implement a proxying property with a different name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler error message

```
note: Objective-C method 'isEnabled' provided by getter for 'enabled' does not match the requirement's selector ('enabled')
```

gives a hint about the problem. The `enabled` property of `UIButton` is inherited from `UIControl` and in Objective-C declared as

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
```

Therefore the protocol method has to be

```
@objc protocol Enableable: class {
    var enabled: Bool { @objc(isEnabled) get set }
}
```

and the implementation (similarly as in [Swift 1.2 error on Objective-C protocol using getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594304/swift-1-2-error-on-objective-c-protocol-using-getter)):

```
extension UIImageView: Enableable {
    var enabled: Bool {
        @objc(isEnabled) get {
            return alpha > DisabledAlpha
        }
        set(enabled) {
            alpha = enabled ? EnabledAlpha : DisabledAlpha
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was wondering if it was due to the signature but was unsure of what to do about it.  We have never seen`@objc protocol Enableable: class {
    var enabled: Bool { @objc(isEnabled) get set }
}`