# Swift 1.2 Extensions

Tags: swift, xcode6.3, swift-extensions

I upgraded XCode to 6.3 / Swift 1.2 and I'm seeing errors with extensions. Below is my extension to UINavigationItem for hiding the backButton text.

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    func backBarButtonItem() -> UIBarButtonItem {
        return UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

When compiled, I get the following error

**Method "backBarButtonItem()" with Objective-C selector "backBarButtonItem" conflicts with getter for "backBarButtonItem"**

Is it not possible to override methods using extensions anymore?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to expose existing property on Obj-C class using an extension protocol in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598680/how-to-expose-existing-property-on-obj-c-class-using-an-extension-protocol-in-sw)

Comment: @nhgrif - I guess the duplicate item you referred to is a different scenario i.e., extensions + protocols. In my case, i'm trying to override an existing property. This code was working in Swift 1.1, after XCode update i'm getting a compilation error.

Comment: change your method name. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are no overriding a property, but **trying to offer a different implementation of (the getter of) a property defined in the same class**.

The first thing to say is that something changed in 6.3 (see [release notes (18391046, 18383574)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html):

> Swift now detects discrepancies between overloading and overriding in the Swift type system and the effective behavior seen via the Objective-C runtime.

That said, you are creating a new `backBarButtonItem` method in an extension. But `UINavigationItem` already has a `backBarButtonItem` property, and for which getter and setter are automatically created, respectively `backBarButtonItem` and `setBackBarButtonItem`. Also to note that the `backBarButtonItem` property is defined in the `UINavigationItem` class, and not inherited from a superclass, so  in this case it's not about overriding.

One could think that converting the method into a computed property would solve the problem. But it doesn't, for the same reason mentioned above: the `backBarButtonItem` property is not inherited, it is defined in the same class.

It's clear that what you want to do is not possible now that Xcode 6.3 fixed the discrepancy.

To prove that, if you try adding that extension to a class inherited from `UINavigationItem`, it works:

```
class MyNavigationItem : UINavigationItem {
}

extension MyNavigationItem {
    override var backBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem? {
        get {
            return UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
        set {
            super.backBarButtonItem = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

To note that you can no longer create a method, because that overrides the property getter (which is not allowed now). You have to override the whole property, making it a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the error message that `backBarButtonItem` is a property, not a method, of `UINavigationItem`. In fact, I just verified that to be the case.

```
var backBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?
```

So you're trying to override a **property** by declaring it as a **method** in the extension. As far as I recall, you can only add **computed** properties (instance or type) to extensions so trying to override `backBarButtonItem` in the extension will not work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The above code was working in Swift 1.1/XCode 6.2.