# Swift protocol property getter for bool values not accepted

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to create a Swift protocol for the WebView class so that it can be used in Javascript. This works fine for most properties, except for a bool property. The reason is that the Obj-C getter behind the scenes is named differently (for a `loading: Bool` property the getter is `isLoading`). How can I specify such a getter in my Swift protocol?

Here's the relevant code:

```
@objc protocol WebViewJSExport : JSExport {
  var mainFrame: WebFrame! { get };
  var selectedFrame: WebFrame! { get };

  var loading: Bool { get };
  var mainFrameURL: String! { get };
  var mainFrameDocument: DOMDocument! { get };
  var mainFrameTitle: String! { get };
}
```

When I use this protocol in my class like this:

```
class WebClient: WebView, WebViewJSExport {
}
```

I get this compiler error (with 2 details entries):

> Type 'WebClient' does not conform to protocol 'WebViewJSExport'
>
> Protocol requires property 'loading' with type 'Bool'
>
> Objective-C method 'isLoading' provided by getter for 'loading' does
>   not match the requirement's selector ('loading')

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this should answer your question: [How to expose existing property on Obj-C class using an extension protocol in Swift][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598680/how-to-expose-existing-property-on-obj-c-class-using-an-extension-protocol-in-sw

Comment: @HomingBrain, your link is the right answer, so please post it as answer so that I can accept it.