# convert obj c to swift code for property

Tags: swift

I have a login page where in obj c, the code is like

```objc
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isLoggedIn) BOOL loggedIn;
```

```objc
if (self.isLoggedIn == NO)
{
    // call a function
}
else
{
    self.loggedIn = NO;

    [self updateUI];
}
```

I need to convert this code to swift, then how do i set the getter=isLoggedIn in the property and use it in swift code as above.

Answer (score 0):

At the top as property of your Object:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
}
```

and then when you need it again:

```
if !self.isLoggedIn
{
// call a function
} else
{
  self.isLoggedIn = false
  self.updateUI()
}
```

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isLoggedIn) BOOL loggedIn;   This is how property is set in obj c

Answer (score 0):

This "getter=isLoggedIn" is something you don't and can't do in Swift. It's an Objective-C-pattern. Just declare the variable as loggedIn and set it as `loggedIn = true` and get it as `Bool isTheUserLoggedIn = loggedIn`.

The class would look like this:

```
class MyClass {
    var loggedIn = false
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598680/how-to-expose-existing-property-on-obj-c-class-using-an-extension-protocol-in-sw

Comment: please check above link, they use the property in swift..but i dont know how to use it

Comment: They use a computed property. So it's not really a property but a value that gets computed every time you grab it.
Why is it so important for you to name the getter isLoggedIn instead of loggedIn?

Comment: To make a distinction between computed and stored properties in Objective-C.  Objective-C doesn't really have quite the same distinction as Swift does...