# Implement Swift protocol with Objective-C property getter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I want to create a common ancestor for all highlightable views in Swift. I wanted that already existing UIKit classes that implement `highlighted` property worked out of the box, so after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29600190/469218) and checking that [the Objective-C getter is defined as `isHighlighted`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620526-highlighted#declarations) I changed the protocol definition to this:

```
@objc protocol Highlightable {
    var highlighted: Bool { @objc(isHighlighted) get set }
}
```

So the protocol implementation for `UILabel` and `UIControl` is as simple as this:

```
extension UILabel: Highlightable {}
extension UIControl: Highlightable {}
```

This works great, I can access and set the `highlighted` property from Swift as `Highlightable` instances. However, when I try to implement the protocol on my Swift classes with even the simplest implementation like this:

```
class HighlightableView: UIView, Highlightable {
    var highlighted: Bool = false
}
```

I get this compilation error:

> Objective-C method 'highlighted' provided by getter for 'highlighted' does not match the requirement's selector ('isHighlighted')

The only way I could get it to work is using computed properties, but it's not what I want.

```
class HighlightableView: UIView, Highlightable {
    var highlighted: Bool { @objc(isHighlighted) get { return true } set {} }
}
```

My environment is Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3. Updated to XCode 8.2 and the error persists.

---

My current workaround is to completely avoid any naming conflict between Objective-C and Swift. But this is far from ideal:

```
@objc protocol Highlightable {
    var _highlighted: Bool { get set }
}

extension UILabel: Highlightable {
    var _highlighted: Bool {
        get { return isHighlighted }
        set { isHighlighted = newValue }
    }
}
extension UIControl: Highlightable {
    var _highlighted: Bool {
        get { return isHighlighted }
        set { isHighlighted = newValue }
    }
}
class HighlightableView: UIView, Highlightable {
    var _highlighted: Bool = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UILabel` and `UIControl` extensions satisfy the way you created your protocol because they already have a property called `highlighted` whose getter accessor method is `isHighlighted`.

Your `HighlightableView` does not satisfy the adoption of your `Highlightable` protocol because you have the `@objc(isHighlighted)` requirement on your getter.

You have to use computed properties to satisfy this. However, this means that you also need a backing store for the `highlighted` property. Something like `private var _highlighted = false`.

In your case, since this is undesirable, you could remove the `@objc` attribute on your protocol.

```
protocol Highlightable: class {
    var highlighted: Bool { get set }
}

extension UILabel: Highlightable { }
extension UIControl: Highlightable { }

class HighlightableView: UIView, Highlightable {
    var highlighted = false
}

let label = UILabel()
label.isHighlighted // Prior to iOS 10, this property is called "highlighted"

let view = HighlightableView()
view.highlighted

let highlightables: [Highlightable] = [ label, view ]

for highlightable in highlightables {
    print(highlightable.highlighted)
}

// Prints:
// false
// false
```

However the property names would not be consistent across the concrete types.

Here is an alternative approach:

```
@objc protocol Highlightable: class {
    var isHighlighted: Bool { @objc(isHighlighted)get @objc(setHighlighted:)set }
}

extension UILabel: Highlightable { }
extension UIControl: Highlightable { }

class HighlightableView: UIView, Highlightable {
    private var _isHighlighted = false
    var isHighlighted: Bool {
        @objc(isHighlighted) get {
            return _isHighlighted
        }
        @objc(setHighlighted:) set {
            _isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}

let label = UILabel()
label.isHighlighted = true

let view = HighlightableView()
view.isHighlighted

let highlightables: [Highlightable] = [ label, view ]

for highlightable in highlightables {
    print(highlightable.isHighlighted)
}

// Prints:
// false
// false
```

This exposes a consistent `isHighlighted` property across all of the concrete types while still conforming to `Highlightable`. The drawback here is the `@objc` attribute is more pervasive in a context where is should not be necessary. That is, the `@objc` attribute is not being used to expose a Swift protocol to Objective-C code.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the iOS 10 API diffs for Swift (and doing some testing in Xcode 7.2), `UILabel` and `UIControl`'s `isHighlighted` property was previously named `highlighted`. Using the code above while linking against iOS SDK 9.3 or lower will result in compile time errors.

In the first example, these errors can be fixed by renaming the `label.isHighlighted` line to `label.highlighted`.

In the second example, these errors can be fixed by renaming all instances of `isHighlighted` to `highlighted` (except for those within the brackets of `@objc` attributes).

9.3 to iOS 10.0 API Differences: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/index.html

Comment: Have you tested your first sample? I can't get it to compile

Comment: @redent84 Yes. It compiles fine for me (Xcode 8.2). Can you share the error?

Comment: It doesn't work for XCode 8.0, but it does work on XCode 8.2.

Comment: Targeting iOS 9.0, your first solution works as expected on XCode 8.2

Comment: @redent84 Thanks for checking. Did you try with the Base SDK set to iOS 9.0? I believe if you only set the Deployment Target to iOS 9.x, this alone will not generate the errors. Instead your Base SDK has to be iOS 9.x. I believe this can only be achieved now by using the Xcode version that ships with the iOS 9.x SDK. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but it's bit bigger than you want, however i think it will help you.

You should do swift protocol and determine default implementation for classes what you need

```
protocol Highlightable: class {
    var highlighted: Bool { get set }
}

extension Highlightable where Self: UILabel {
    var highlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return isHighlighted
        }
        set {
            isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension Highlightable where Self: UIControl {
    var highlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return isHighlighted
        }
        set {
            isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

So you could implement it

```
extension UILabel: Highlightable {}
extension UIControl: Highlightable {}

class CustomView: UIView, Highlightable {
    var highlighted: Bool = false
}
```

I hope it helps you.